# Selenium - no module named http.client

Tags: python, selenium

I just installed Selenium (from source) for Python 2.7.

When I try to `import selenium`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.25.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .selenium import selenium
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.25.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\selenium.py", line 19, in <module>
    import http.client
ImportError: No module named http.client
```

What could be causing this? If I remember correctly, http.client is a python 3 module. Why is selenium trying to import it?

Comment: Yeah, that's 3.  I just downloaded 2.25.0 from [this link](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium#downloads) and line 19 of `selenium.py` is `import httplib`.  The only way I can get `import http.client` is if I run `python3 setup.py install` which runs `2to3`, and then somehow force that version to be installed under 2.  Someone with more windows knowledge may be able to explain the circumstances under which that might occur.

Comment: I've had problems with python 2 and 3 conflicting in the past. I'll try a fresh install again.

Comment: @DSM I'm running `python27 setup.py install` and it seems to end up, like you said, running the 2to3 tool and installing the converted code in my python27 libraries. Do you know of any way I could disable this?

Comment: First confirm that `setup_python3()` is being called in setup.py.  Look at what `sys.version_info` returns.  If it isn't obvious at that point -- maybe it's strange for some reasoon -- then simply replace that line by `if 0:` and see if it follows the right branch.

Comment: Thanks so much, I figured it out! Because I had previously ran `setup.py` with a python3 executable by accident, the `build` folder was populated with `2to3` converted code. When I ran python27 setup.py install it didn't overwrite the `build` folder. I ended up deleting the `build` folder and trying again, and it works.

Comment: you should make that an answer.

Comment: @PeterHansen I guess I forgot to accept it. Thanks for reminding me about a year later. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the help of DSM, I figured it out. Because I had previously ran setup.py with a python3 executable by accident, the selenium build folder was populated with 2to3 converted code. When I later ran `python27 setup.py install` it ended up using the same build folder for the installation without overwriting its content. I ended up deleting the build folder and trying again, and it works.