# Selenium Python Ubuntu- Import http.client AttributeError

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-webdriver, http.client

It's been days i'm fighting with this error. 
My background is : 
- Clean install of Lubuntu ( based on ubuntu 15 ) w/ just setuptools and selenium 2.50 installed
- A selenium python3 script.

I tried running this script w/ an other machine ( lubuntu based on ubuntu 14 ) and it runs, but with the new machine, all the scripts doesn't work.
I looked up on the big internet but i couldn't find an answer.
I have the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tesst.py", line 1, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-2.50.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from selenium import selenium
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-2.50.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/selenium.py", line 23, in <module>
import http.client as http_client
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
import email.parser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
from email.feedpaarser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
from email import message
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
from email import utils
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 33, in <module>
from email._parseaddr import quote
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
import time, calendar
File "/home/XXXX/Scripts/XXXX/calendar.py", line 1, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-2.50.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-2.50.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 20, in <module>
import http.client as http_client
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from apport.report import Report
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
from urllib.request import urlopen
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
import http.client
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
import email.parser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
from email import message
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
from email import utils
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 33, in <module>
from email._parseaddr import quote
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
import time, calendar
File "/home/XXXX/Scripts/XXXX/calendar.py", line 1, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-2.50.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from selenium import selenium
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-2.50.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/selenium.py", line 23, in <module>
import http.client as http_client
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tesst.py", line 1, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-2.50.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from selenium import selenium
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-2.50.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/selenium.py", line 23, in <module>
import http.client as http_client
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
import email.parser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
from email import message
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
from email import utils
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 33, in <module>
from email._parseaddr import quote
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
import time, calendar
File "/home/XXXX/Scripts/XXXX/calendar.py", line 1, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-2.50.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-2.50.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 20, in <module>
    import http.client as http_client
```

I looked a lot before coming here but i'm kinda lost right now. Can someone please help, i'll be very greatful.
Thanks !!

Edit :

Hey, i already try all of that, but it's not fixing the issue. I don't have duplicate selenium, i just install 
`sudo python3 setup.py install` in selenium dir. Also i don't have a script called http.py, so when i do `import http http.__file__` it gives me `/usr/lib/python3.4/http/__init__.py`

Comment: it's very simple module http doesn't have attribute client and you are trying to import it by using import http.client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - no module named http.client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058647/selenium-no-module-named-http-client)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25278648/2546966) might help to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's face it, i knew it, the answer was just in front of my eyes. S**t !!
This 
    File "/home/XXXX/Scripts/XXXX/calendar.py", line 1, in

I had a script name calendar.py as a module... So changing the name made the job.

Sorry guys, and thank you